# get Server's SPF record

Tags: php, extjs, dns, spf

I need to create simple code with PHP+ Ext JS, when SPF record of any domain is readed and further processed.

I had found sites like
http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html
where i can get the SPF record on the site.

But i need this info inside my PHP+JS code, i need to process it, to show and to save new updated one.

Is there any command in PHP JS using that i can get SPF record and save it?

Urmas.

Comment: why do you want to add record to php?

Answer (score 7):

SPF is a txt DNS record, so just use `dns_get_record ($hostname , DNS_TXT)` to get all the txt records (it returns an array) and check each if it contains `v=spf1`

Comment: If someone has an include in the record; then you need to interpret that and get that record as well. In the case of Google Apps you have to get about 5 records to have the entire list of authorized IPs.

Answer (score 1):

You should take into consideration that the SPF standard is quite complex and there are many things which people do wrong. I suggest you read about it more to make sure your implementation is covering all the checks that you need.

This is a very good resource to learn more about SPF:
http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax

Here is the technical documentation:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408

There is more to it than just getting the TXT record of a domain. For PHP versions older than 5 you could use `shell_exec("dig example.com TXT @nameserver");` on a unix based system.

Answer (score 1):

check this code. It may be helpful for someone

```
<?php
include("util.php");
$exists = false;
$array = dns_get_record("amazon.com", DNS_ALL);
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array) - 1; $i++) {
    $nestedarray = $array[$i];
    for ($j = 0; $j <= count($nestedarray) - 1; $j++) {
        if (array_key_exists("txt", $nestedarray)) {
            $str = $nestedarray['txt'];
            $search = "v=spf1";
            if (preg_match("/{$search}/i", $str)) {
                echo (prepareAPIResponse("success", $str, "found"));
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
if (!$exists) {
    echo (prepareAPIResponse("error", null, "not found"));
}

function prepareAPIResponse($status='success', $data=null, $msg=null)
{
    header('content-type: application/json');
    return json_encode([
       'status'=>$status,
       'data'=>$data,
       'message'=>$msg
    ]);
}
```